# Android Admob Banners don't show

Tags: android, admob, banner

I have a problem:

I use Eclipse with ADT and banners don't show in Google Ads sample application, I don't know why.

Mannifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.gms.samples.ads"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <!-- Used to request banner and interstitial ads. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Used to avoid sending an ad request if there is no connectivity. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.samples.ads.GoogleAdsSampleActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".BannerXmlActivity"
            android:label="@string/banner_in_xml"/>
        <activity android:name=".BannerCodeActivity"
            android:label="@string/banner_in_code"/>
        <activity android:name=".InterstitialActivity"
            android:label="@string/interstitial"/>
        <!-- Activity required to show ad overlays. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Code

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_banner_code_ad_listener);

        mAdView = new AdView(this);
        mAdView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/4xxxxxxxxx");
        mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

        final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        layout.addView(mAdView);

        mAdView.setAdListener(new ToastAdListener(this));
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("AAxAxxxAxAxxxAxxxAxxxAAxxAxxxAA")
        .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Project-Property:

```
target=android-18
android.library.reference.1=../google-play-services_lib
```

In LogCat:

```
Google Play services out of date.  Requires 6587000 but found 5089030

GooglePlayServices not available due to error 2

VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8193: Landroid/webkit/WebView;.evaluateJavascript (Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/webkit/ValueCallback;)V

JS: The page at https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html displayed insecure content from file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png.

The page at https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html displayed insecure content from file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png.

JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_buildAdURL is not defined (null:1)

Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_buildAdURL is not defined at null:1
```

Application work, but no banner. With the listener, I see I have an internal Error.

Internet work, I have google-play-services_lib rev 22 included in project.

I have tried in another phone but same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Always build your project with the newest target:

```
android:targetSdkVersion="21"
```

also try updating your Google Play Services (GMS) via the SDK manager.

Comment: I changed project-property: target=android-21 and manifest: android:targetSdkVersion="21" but same thing. In SDK Manager, Google play services has no more update, the rev is 22 and I don't find Google Play Services (GMS).

Answer (score 0):

The version of Google Play Services on your device is out of date.

On your device, go to Google Play and look for an update for it.

Comment: In Google Store, when I search Google Play Services, it don't show.

Answer (score 0):

add to your manifest
but point your APPLICATION_ID in second line

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-11111111111111~222222222"/>
```